# Issue with loading R packages within a container

Tags: r

I'm encountering an issue with the .libPaths() function in R, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve it. I have a setup where I'm running R within a Docker container, and I'm experiencing unexpected behavior with the library paths.

Here's a brief overview of the problem:

1. I have a script called `xxxxxx.sh` that installs certain libraries at the location `/home/file/.....` , and gives the logs of successful installation.
2. The `xxxxx.sh` file invokes another R file using `/usr/bin/Rscript setup.R`.
3. However, when `setup.R` runs, it tries to load the library using `library(yyyyy)` command, the error shown is `library(yyyy) : there is no package called 'yyyyy'`.
4. Further to debug, I added the command `list.files('/home/file/.....')`, which gives the output character(0)

I have verified the following:

1.The Docker container setup seems to be correct, as other users have successfully run their applications using the same Docker base image.

2.The .Renviron file is empty.

3.The installation of packages in install_libraries_as_root.sh appears to be successful